# How to add a day to date field value in Django views

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
my_date = request.POST.get('to_date')
to_date = datetime.strptime(my_date,"%Y-%m-%d") + timedelta(days=1)
```

This however gives me an error:

> strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime.

So I tried this:

```
my_date = request.POST.get('to_date')
to_date = my_date + timedelta(days=1)
```

This treats the my_date value as a string and gives the error:

> can only concatenate str (not "datetime.timedelta") to str.

If I print `type(my_date)` it says `<class 'str'>`. Can someone please advise on how to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Date you are getting from `request.POST` is string. First you need to convert string to date object.

```
In [1]: import datetime
In [2]: strDate = '22-1-2020'
In [3]: my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, "%d-%m-%Y")
In [4]: to_date = my_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
In [5]: to_date
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 23, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Actually, the `.date()` is not required. The following works as well: `datetime.datetime.strptime(strDate, "%d-%m-%Y") + datetime.timedelta(days=1)`